# mongoid , will_paginate , sorting doesnt work with Mongoid criteria DSL

Tags: sorting, mongoid, will-paginate

According to the readme of mongoid on github i can do fancy queries like 
Person.select(:first_name, :last_name).where(:title => "Sir").skip(10).limit(10).paginate

i tried this in combination with will_paginate (3.0.pre2)

```
@companies = Company.paginate(:per_page=>5, :page=>params[:page], :sort => [sort_column, sort_direction])
```

---> works fine

```
@companies = Company.all.paginate(:per_page=>5, :page=>params[:page], :sort => [sort_column, sort_direction])
```

---> sorting doesnt work anymore

i tried

```
@companies = Company.where(:name=>/^#{params[:search]}/).paginate( :per_page=>5, :page=>params[:page], :sort => [sort_column, sort_direction])
```

--> doesnt work

then

```
@companies = Company.paginate(:conditions=>{:name=>/^#{params[:search]}/}, :per_page=>5, :page=>params[:page], :sort => [sort_column, sort_direction])
```

---> works

But i think search functions should be in the model not in the controller! ?

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

Don't use sort in paginate, use `order_by()` instead. For example:

company model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if !search.blank?
   where(:name => /^#{search}/)
  else
   all
  end
end
```

company controller (index):

```
 @companies = Company.search(params[:search]).order_by([sort_column, sort_direction]).paginate(:per_page=>5, :page=>params[:page])
```